# Finding GEO Location of user, then outputting php

Tags: php, html

I want my site to tell the browser to ask the user "Share your location"

Once location is shared, I'd like if the output was based on different locations,

So location A (united kingdom) would output div1, div2, div3

Location B (africa) would output div4 div5 div6

etc

This would not be based on actual house locations, but regions.  Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="init.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="location">
        <div style="display: none;" id="div1">Div 1</div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="div2">Div 2</div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="div3">Div 3</div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="div4">Div 4</div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="div5">Div 5</div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="div6">Div 6</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

init.js:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#location").on("input", function(){
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + $("#location").val() + "&key=API KEY HERE", true);
        client.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if(client.readyState == 4) {
               var results = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
               if(results.results[0].address_components[0].short_name == 'GB') {
                   $('#div1, #div2, #div3').show();
                   $('#div4, #div5, #div6').hide();
               } else if (results.results[0].address_components[0].short_name == 'Africa') {
                   $('#div4, #div5, #div6').show();
                   $('#div1, #div2, #div3').hide();

               }
        };
        };

        client.send();
    });
});
```

Be sure to get your own API key here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#api_key